# How do I get a YouTube FLV URL?

Tags: url, download, youtube, flv

Looking through the site, every question uses an outdated method. How do the YouTube FLV downloader websites/applications do it?

I am trying to do this in PHP but the theory or steps to do it will suffice, thanks.

Comment: Ah might want to look at the source over at file2hd.com

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As mentioned in other posts, you may want to look at our code in
[youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) (or in the code of the Firefox extension called
[FlashVideoReplacer](https://github.com/webgapps/flvideoreplacer)).

In the particular case of youtube-dl, the "real work" is done in the
subclasses of `InformationExtractor` and it hard to give a "stable" answer,
as the layout of such sites changes constantly.

There are some pieces of the information that are not dynamic, such as, for
instance, the uploader of the video, the title, the date of upload, and,
most importantly, the identifier of the video (a 11-character string).

For the dynamic parts, what can be said about such tools is that,
essentially, the URLs generated by such videos are dynamically generated and
you need to perform some back-and-forth communication with the server.

It is important to have in mind that what such sites can (and do) take into
consideration depend on a number of parameters, including: the cookies that
you have already received---as the case for HTML5 videos, your
geolocation---for regional control, your age--for "strong" material, your
language/locale---for showing content tailored to you, etc.

youtube-dl uses a regular expression to extract the video ID from the URL
that you give and, then, uses a "normalized", typical URL as used from the
United States, from which to proceed.

*Some* of the dynamic data to be gathered includes:

- some time-stamp (the `expire`, and `fexp` parts of the final URL)
- the cookies sent to the browser
- the format in which we want to download the video (the `itag` part of the final URL)
- throttling information (the `algorithm`, `burst`, `factor`)
- some hashes/tokens used internally by them (e.g., the `signature` part of the final URL)

Some of the information listed above were once not required, but now they
are (in particular, the cookies that they send you). This means that the
information listed above is very likely to become obsolete, as the controls
become stricter.

You can see some of the work (with respect to the cookies) that I did in
this regard in the implementation of an external backend to use an external
downloader (a "download accelerator") with what youtube-dl extracts.

Discloser: I have committed some changes to the repository, and I maintain
the `youtube-dl` package in Debian (and, as a side effect, in Ubuntu).

Comment: Nice work with youtube-dl, its nice to find something useful like that which is easy to use and actively maintained.

Comment: @AndyDunn, youtube-dl has gained support for many other sites since I wrote that answer and the newest changes. Seeing one of the simpler `InformationExtractors` is a good way of understanding how the principles of scraping for the videos work.

Comment: thanks a bunch for pointing that out. That makes a massive difference to what I'm doing, knowing that it can also work for the other websites too ! :)

Comment: @rbrito I have a tip: use the host `http://www.youtube-nocookie.com` to avoid cookie validation, localStorage mandatory id and JavaScript encryption with cookie being mandatory for signature and id. essentially an 'incognito mode' also, in additional I'm sending in the PHP the header `DNT: 1` and the server should respect that avoiding tracking the user-session by IP.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to take a look at how [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/) downloads the files.  As YouTube changes, that program does seem to get updated rather quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube doesn't store FLV files, they compile your video into a SWF object. Those videos need to be either extracted or converted to FLV in order to get the FLV.

http://www.youtube.com/v/videoid

ex:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6nRb45I3e4
```

becomes

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/C6nRb45I3e4
```

From there, you need to convert the SWF into an flv, which can be done with [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/).

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I asked for.

Comment: Yes it is, there is no url for flv files, because there are no FLV files. They are compiled within SWF objects. You have to decompile with ffmpeg to get the flv out. The SWF is located as mentioned.

Comment: ?? YouTube streams FLV files to the player. They don't upload a unique, seperate SWF file with the video embedded.

Comment: When you upload a video to youtube, it's embedded within a few unique players, that's why older videos still have the pre-google renovation themes UI.

Comment: I need a method of obtaining the direct FLV URL.

Comment: I've explained this, they grab the swf and extract the flv.

Comment: @Korvin: Not correct. You can demonstrate this with Apple's Safari. While a YouTube video is playing, open the Activity window. The line with the large and increasing size is the video. Copy this URL. Now get this URL with wget (or similar) and you'll see it is a .flv file. It should be obvious that wget has not downloaded a .swf file and extracted anything. It has downloaded the .flv file directly.

Comment: if using `FFMPEG`, you are better off just downloading a `MP4` resource in the first-place, and encode it to `FLV`.

Comment: @EladKarako Youtube is a different beast 4 years later :P

Comment: @korvin-szanto, the embedded code of the video-player still uses the flash-player (the link to the iframe code is available under the HTML5-video). In addition using `www.youtube-nocookie.com` instead of `www.youtube.com` will free you from cookie/localStorage anti-bot mechanism (may also add the `DNT 1 DO_NOT_TRACK` header), the easiest way to get the video-resources now days is to rip the `ytplayer.config.args` (from client-side-- JavaScript) or parse `https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/get_video_info?el=detailpage&asv=3&video_id=YOUR_VIDEO_ID`... Just a tip

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to get an url of youtube video in flv or mp4 mode then use "YouTube Downloader - Version: 5.0" in Chrome you can right click on download button and copy path.

![You can get url of any format from this button][1]

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFUWr.jpg (see this url due to i can't upload image at this time)
```

You can click on this button and copy url from "chrome://downloads/"
I think this may help you.